# iOS 7 simulator vs device vs Storyboard UI differences

Tags: iphone, ios7, simulator

Upgrading my app for iOS 7 is a challenge.  The UI is built from IB but does not use auto layout.

On IB I unchecked the Extend Edges boxes for my view controllers.  Now in IB it all looks correct for iOS 7 and iOS 6.

Extend Edges unchecked:

[image: IB Extend Edges]

Storyboard appearance:

[image: IB Button]
[image]

Segmented Control tint:

[image]

On Simulator the content still extends behind the navbar unless I make the navbar opaque.  It seems to just ignore the fact the Extend Edges where unchecked.

Simulator Appearance:

[image]
[image]

On an iPhone 5 running iOS 7 the content also extends under the navbar.  In addition, all the navbar buttons have iOS 6 look.  The segmented control also seems to be ignoring the tint and displaying black on black.

iPhone 5 running iOS 7 Appearance:

[image]
[image]

Can someone explain what's happening here and how I can get the iOS 7 appearance on IB, Simulator, and device to match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent days on this and was astounded by the variety of displays I saw.  Not only were the buttons not displaying correctly but I also was getting different UIView frame dimensions on the simulator between iOS 6 & 7.  I also saw differences in the frame between the simulator and iOS 7 device.

I was tracking down a different problem and realized my iOS device showed up twice on Xcode 5's destination menu.  I found out that occurs when you have more than one iOS SDK installed in Xcode.  I removed the iOS 6.1 SDK from the Xcode 5 application and all my issues went away.

I can't be sure it wasn't related to me picking a different device from the menu each time.  I understand one shows up for each SDK installed.  They were named the same so I never knew which one to choose.

Again, not sure this caused all my problems but I don't have them now.  Hopefully this will save someone a ton of time tracking down UI anomalies.

Comment: Had the same issue, picking the second device (and subsequently removing the 6.1 sdk symlink) fixed it. My issue was that I got the iOS6 UI on a iOS7 device...